# how to install sqlite3 in Raspberry Pi

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3

How to install Sqlite3 in Raspberry Pi.

I tried to do it with :

> sudo apt-get install sqlite3

but getting following error :

> Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.resbian.org'
>   unable to fetch some archive, may be run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get update before trying to install sqlite3 on a fresh installation.

Comment: tried this also , but again getting errors like : Failed to fetch  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org

Comment: Silly question but , are you connected to the internet ?

Comment: yes I am connected. :-)